# How to get instance of child component up to n'th level in tree structure

Tags: angular, angular5

I want the instance of header-group component in recursive format.
for example:
like
 1st header-group having 2 header-group child and 2nd header-group having 1 column child in tree structure.

This is my **app.component.html**

```html
<header-group>
  <header-group>
    <column></column>
  </header-group>
  <header-group>
    <column></column>
  </header-group>
</header-group>
```

I am Having 2 component header and column.

This is my **header component**

```js
/**
 * Created by dattaram on 13/4/18.
 */
import {AfterContentInit, AfterViewInit, Component, ContentChildren, Input, OnInit, QueryList} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'header-group',
  template:`
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  `
})

export class HeaderGroupComponent implements OnInit, AfterContentInit, AfterViewInit {

  @Input() label: any;

  @ContentChildren(HeaderGroupComponent) headerRef: QueryList<HeaderGroupComponent>;

  @ContentChildren(ColumnComponent) columnRef: QueryList<ColumnComponent>;


   data: any[] = [];

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.data.push(this.headerRef.toArray());
    console.log(this.data);
  }
}
```

This is my **column Component**:

```js
import {Input, Component, ContentChild, TemplateRef} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'column', template: `
  I am Column
  `
})
export class ColumnComponent {

  @Input() text: string;
}
```